# how to getattribute of a span class value in selenium web driver

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, gettext, getattribute

I used .getAttribute("value"); but it gives null value
.gettext() method also gives null value.Kindly suggest way forward.[Snapshot of xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PooXV.png)

```
<span class="required-filled ng-binding" ng-hide="appc.model.oRareCaratSignup.msgError">Please fill required fields</span>
```

Absolute xpath for the element is:

```
html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/span[2]
```

Comment: As you mentioned `it have multiple span with class required-filled ng-binding` can you share a bit more of the `outerHTML` so a unique attribute can be identified?

Comment: cssselector() is a better mechanism instead of cumbersome xpath.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your element is hidden. So you have to get `innerText` instead of the text because `getText()` will check visibility of the element. If it is hidden, you will get a blank text.

```
element.getAttribute("innerText");
```

Comment: not working gives blank value. tried with element.getAttribute("innerText"); as well as element.getAttribute("innerHTML");

Comment: @abhishek Can you tell me what is the output of `element.getAttribute("outerHTML");`?

Comment: Value of classNameValue attribute: <span ng-hide="appc.model.oRareCaratSignup.msgError" class="required-filled ng-binding ng-hide"></span>

Comment: @abhishek I guess there are 2 possibilities. 1. You didn't add enough wait time. 2. You get an incorrect element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
WebElement TxtBoxContent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/span[2]"));
String Txt = TxtBoxContent.getText();
System.out.println(Txt);
```

Comment: Can you provide some more of your HTML so that it can provide a better glimpse to the issue to all.?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, try a relative xpath. The span contains text, so it should have the attribute Text.

First thing I would do is, open the page in chrome. Then hit F12 (dev tools), and go to the Console tab. There, typ:

```
$x("//span[@class='required-filled ng-binding']")
```

Assuming this is the only span with class "required-filled ng-binding"

Once you find your span, expand the nodes in Chrome and check if the text attribute is filled. If it is, in your code the gettext() should work. If it doesn't it could be a timing issue as there is Angular involved. In that case, just for trial/error purposes, throw in a thread.sleep before getting the element and see if it helps.

Comment: it have multiple span with class required-filled ng-binding  and i am waiting foe 5sec though it did not worked out

Answer (score 0):

I could never deduce why, but I had a similar issue with how the developers coded the text for some checkboxes in a modal.

In reality, the xpath/css/id/whatever is working (otherwise you'd see an object cannot be found error). The problem is Selenium is not reading the text within it correctly. In the end, I found this to work:

```
.getAttribute("textContent").trim()
```

So find it however you wish, but use this instead of .getText()